# How do you loop through a Django queryset in an html file?

Tags: python, django

I  have a view that contains code to retrieve all review objects for a movie:

```
review = Review.objects.filter(movie= movie)
```

How can I loop through these values **in the html** so that I only get the first 3 review objects? Indexing like review[0] doesn't seem to work.

I saw in another post that you can loop through all of the objects in the html like this (but this is not what I am looking for):

```
{% for obj in review %} 
  <p> {% obj.review_text %} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just get the first 3 items only in your view and only return those into the context? That seems like it would be the simplest solution.

```
first_3_reviews = Review.objects.filter(movie= movie)[:3]
```

Alternatively, you could use the forloop counter (see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to only display the first 3 elements:

```
{% for obj in review %} 
  {% if forloop.counter < 3 %} 
    <p> {% obj.review_text %} </p>
  {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This answer is great and works. I agree that this should be done in the view. Thank you for these solutions.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how would you go about filtering the last 3 items instead of the first 3. I tried review = Review.objects.filter(movie= movie).reverse()[:3]. This didn't work

Comment: To get the last three items you have to filter the queryset first. The hyphen before '-id' is important and orders the queryset in ascending order. This is the code I used: review = Review.objects.filter(movie= movie).order_by('-id')[:3]

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
{% for obj in review %}
<p> {{% obj.review_text %}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

It will give you option to use your object easily

Comment: This doesn't address my question. I included that code in my original post

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for obj in review[-3:] %}
```

this retrieves the last 3 items in review